# how to get list of members using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I tried to do this
[image: preview]

```
URL=str(browser.current_url)
page=requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
imena = soup.findAll('a', class_='text-headline')
imena
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the URL is for the Members tab of the [Starva](https://www.strava.com/) club [Россия 2021](https://www.strava.com/clubs/236545/), i.e., https://www.strava.com/clubs/236545/members the following should work to get all of the members across the 193 pages (you really should be using the [Strava API](https://developers.strava.com/)...):

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

BASE_URL = "https://www.strava.com/clubs/236545/members?page="

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(f"{BASE_URL}{1}")
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("<your-email>")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("<your-password>")
driver.find_element_by_id("login-button").click()

time.sleep(1)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

num_pages = int(soup.find("ul", "pagination").find_all("li")[-2].text)

# Ignore the admins shown on each page
athletes = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "list-athletes"})[1]
members = [
    avatar.attrs['title']
    for avatar in athletes.find_all("div", {"class": "avatar"})
    if 'title' in avatar.attrs
]
for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.get(f"{BASE_URL}{page}")
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    athletes = soup.find_all("ul", {"class": "list-athletes"})[1]
    for avatar in athletes.find_all("div", {"class": "avatar"}):
        if 'title' in avatar.attrs:
            members.append(avatar.attrs['title'])

# Print first 10 members
print('\n'.join(m.strip() for m in members[:10]))

driver.close()
```

**Output (first 10 members):**

```
- Victor Koldaev  -    ♥LCHF Runners♥
Antonio Raposo ®️
Vadim Issin
"DuSenna Vá com Garra e a Felicidade te Agarra 
#MIX MIX
#RunВасяRun ...
$ерЖ  КЛИМoff
'Luis Fernando Osorio' MTB
( CE )Faisal ALShammary "حائل $الشرقية "
(# Monique #) bermudez
```

Comment: and how i can get the count of follows of each user. i  want to сreate a dict with key=name_user and value=follow.value_count

Comment: You need to get the id from somewhere close to where I got the name above and save that in a tuple with the name. Then loop over the list of the tuples going to each users athlete page to find the followers from that page e.g.  `https://www.strava.com/athletes/8239299`  and then you should be able to create the dict one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the "text-headline" elements div and then loop through each of them to get the anchor links.

```
URL=str(browser.current_url)
page=requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
members = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'text-headline'})
for (member in members):
   name = member.find("a")
   print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)